# Computing $\pi_3(\mathrm{Gr}_2(\mathbb{R}^4))$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

**How can one go about computing the 3rd homotopy group of the Grassmannian manifold of 2-planes through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^4$?**

I don't want to be more general in the question, because:
1) I think this is related to homotopy groups of spheres which is currently intractable.
2) This particular group pops up in my thoughts on vector bundles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\text{Gr}_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$ is the homogeneous space $\text{O}(4)/(\text{O}(2) \times \text{O}(2))$ and as such it fits into a fibration

$$\text{O}(2) \times \text{O}(2) \to \text{O}(4) \to \text{Gr}_2(\mathbb{R}^4).$$

The higher homotopy groups of $\text{O}(2) \times \text{O}(2)$ vanish, so the associated long exact sequence shows that $\pi_3(\text{Gr}_2(\mathbb{R}^4)) \cong \pi_3(\text{O}(4))$. To compute the latter, note that

$$\pi_3(\text{O}(4)) \cong \pi_3(\text{SO}(4)) \cong \pi_3(\text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2))$$

since higher homotopy groups are invariant up to taking covering spaces. Note also that $\text{SU}(2) \cong S^3$ satisfies $\pi_3(S^3) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, so the answer is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Perfect! Haha the first time I decide not to give you a call, you end up helping anyway!

Comment: There might be a slight technical problem with choosing a basepoint since $O(n)$ is not connected.

Comment: @user: for topological groups there is always a canonical choice of basepoint, namely the identity.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Well, $\pi_3$ is a functor from the category of topological spaces to the category of groups, so it ignores the group structure of the input $O(n)$. If you choose the identity as the basepoint, then the first isomorphism in your calculation should be an equality (by definition) rather than isomorphism: $\pi_3(O(4))=\pi_3(SO(4))$.

Comment: @user: as you already pointed out $\pi_3$ is, of course, a functor from *pointed* topological spaces to groups. Topological groups are canonically pointed by the identity. And it doesn't really matter whether I write an equality or an isomorphism there.

Answer (score 8):

$Gr_2(\mathbb R^4)$ is the quotient $O_4 / O_2 \times O_2$, which is double covered by $SO_4 / SO_2 \times SO_2$.  $SO_4$ is double-covered by $S^3 \times S^3$.   So $Gr_2(\mathbb R^4)$ has $(S^3 / SO_2)^2$ as a covering space, and this is just $(S^2)^2$.   So $\pi_3 Gr_2(\mathbb R^4)$ is the same as $\pi_3 (S^2 \times S^2)$ which is a free abelian group of rank two.

Comment: Perfect! I should definitely have viewed it as a homogeneous space.